# Is it possible for a malicious user to edit $_SESSION?

Tags: php, session

I save some important info in `$_SESSION`, not in `$_COOKIE`. So, my question, is it dangerous? Or is it protected from malicious users trying to edit it and I'm fine?
Thank you.

By the way, is it possible also to edit `$_COOKIE`? I heard yes, but if yes, then how?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`$_SESSION` is stored server-side. The best a hacker could do would be substitute another user's session for the existing session, but the hacker could not insert arbitrary data into `$_SESSION`. `$_COOKIE` is, however, stored client-side, so a hacker can insert arbitrary data into the cookie, by just editing the cookie.

Answer (score 7):

By default, the `$_SESSION` is already backed by a cookie with the name `phpsessionid` (so that the server is able to identify the client and associate it with one of the sessions in server's memory). If a hacker knows the cookie value of someone else and copies it in its own cookie with the same name on the same domain/path, then the hacker has access to the same `$_SESSION`. The cookie value is however long and random enough to minimize the risks the session being hijacked within half a hour (the default session timeout).

Answer (score 3):

$_SESSION is stored on your webserver, so it's not possible to directly alter it via the web. Of course, your PHP application can update $_SESSION, so it still might be possible for an attacker to trick your application into doing something to $_SESSION that it shouldn't - it all depends on the specifics of your application.

$_COOKIE is stored on the user's browser, which means that the user has the power to change their own cookies.

One of the main uses for cookies is authentication. A user logs in and information is stored in $_SESSION. A cookie (stored in $_COOKIE) records the session id of the user so that your application knows which session belongs to the logged-in user.

Comment: I've never seen a memory based session data store.

Comment: A common performance optimization is to use memcached to store PHP session data - (example of a memory-based session data store)

Answer (score 3):

If you're worried about people altering sessions (session hijacking) look into [`session_regenerate_id()`](http://php.net/session_regenerate_id)

Answer (score 1):

Yes Hacker can hijack the session  you can use `session_regenerate_id()`  , or stole it 
 look 
  if you are admin and you logged in ,( session is in the server )
  hacker have it via xss  = > will make cookie in his pc with this session and log , change the pass or add admin , besore the end of the session

---

cookie can stole too ,
  look this code
 
 `setcookie("admin","admin_log",time()+3600);`

 if hacker know the code  like opensource  he can log as
 make cookie by firefox addons  as the cookie name and value

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are sent via the user-agent every time a page is requested. The user-agent doesn't need to be a browser. It could be a small shell script. Even if it is a browser, there's an "edit cookie" extension for Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

$_COOKIE contains information that the client sent to your web server. Most commonly this is the contents of browser cookies but t could contain ANYTHING, so don't trust it.