# Is there a way to see/edit my session in a website?

Tags: php, session

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to edit $_SESSION by hacker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976821/is-it-possible-to-edit-session-by-hacker)

My question is mainly for security reasons because I am building a website that uses sessions and handles the ID and ROLE of a user to show some specific content.

This session is created on successful login.

Is there a way to edit a session and for example change his ID or ROLE to something else, so he will be able to gain access somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

No. Session data is written in a file on the web server that's not accessible by any web user, except through setting `$_SESSION` variables in code.

So as long as you don't `eval()` user input, you're safe with sessions. The only thing that links a user to its specific piece of session data is the cookie with the session ID, which can manually be changed. If you have a lot of active sessions, they might guess a valid session ID and hijack someone else's session.

Comment: If you're concerned about `eval`, you should be concerned about `include` as well. Next to that, what about an attacker editing files on the server or in case a database store is used, uses sql injection to change session data?

Answer (score 0):

For a better information:

Refer this exisiting URL: **[Is it possible for a malicious user to edit $_SESSION?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976821/is-it-possible-to-edit-session-by-hacker)**

Answer (score -2):

session variables are just normal variables.

```
$_SESSION['id']=1;
```

to edit it, simply assign it another number

```
$_SESSION['id']=2;
```

if you want to see the content of a session:

```
var_dump($_SESSION);
```