# Are the $_SESSION variables accessible by the user?

Tags: php, session-variables

I made a user authentification script for a password protected page.

In the first version of my script I started by checking if the user name and password matched the ones in the database and if yes, set a $_SESSION['user_connected'] variable as well as a $_COOKIE['user_connected'] variable to TRUE. My index.php file started by verifying if $_COOKIE['user_connected'] was set and then bypassed the database check if true.

I then realized cookies were accessible by the user and someone could simply set $_COOKIE['user_connected'] to TRUE before accessing the site and chaos would ensue. But what about the $_SESSION variables ? Can I securely use them to check throughout the website if the user is connected ?

tl;dr : Can users modify $_SESSION variables ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to edit $_SESSION by hacker?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976821/is-it-possible-to-edit-session-by-hacker)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.

They are stored on the server and only editable by scripts running on the server.

The user only gets a token that identifies which bundle of data is associated with them.

Answer (score 5):

> Possible duplicate: [Is it possible for a malicious user to edit $_SESSION?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976821/is-it-possible-to-edit-session-by-hacker)

`$_SESSION` is server side, once it is set it cannot be changed (by the user)

Also, take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976821/is-it-possible-to-edit-session-by-hacker)

Comment: Thanks, I tried to search with "is $_SESSION accessible / modify / change" but I missed the word "edit".